# How do i save and load with streamwriter and streamreader

Tags: c#

I have 3 forms, the main form with a month calendar and a panel which shows any appointment, and two others,form2 and form3 that are opening with a button from the main form. what i want is to have a save button in form2 and form3 and when it is pressed, save all information enter in textboxes and selected from combobox and when the application close and open up again, the information should load and show in the panel.(with streamwriter and streamreader)

I tried the xml method but i can't find out what to do so i hope that this method will help me!

Comment: Which forms Winform or WebForm?

Comment: Oh, Winform ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an XML solution

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";

        List<TextBox> boxes = null;
        List<ComboBox> cboxes = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.FormClosing +=  new FormClosingEventHandler(Form1_FormClosing);
            boxes = new List<TextBox>() { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3 };
            cboxes = new List<ComboBox>() { comboBox1, comboBox2, comboBox3 };

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            Root newRoot = (Root)xs.Deserialize(reader);

            foreach (TextBox tBox in boxes)
            {
                string name = tBox.Name;
                Box box = newRoot.boxes.Where(x => x.name == name).FirstOrDefault();
                tBox.Text = box.rows[0];
            }
            foreach (ComboBox  cBox in cboxes)
            {
                string name = cBox.Name;
                Box box = newRoot.boxes.Where(x => x.name == name).FirstOrDefault();
                foreach (string row in box.rows)
                {
                    cBox.Items.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Root root = new Root();
            root.boxes = new List<Box>();
            foreach(TextBox tBox in boxes)
            {
                Box newBox = new Box() { name = tBox.Name, type = "Text", 
                    rows = new List<string>(){tBox.Text}
                };
            }
            foreach (ComboBox  cBox in cboxes)
            {
                Box newBox = new Box()
                {
                    name = cBox.Name,
                    type = "Combo",
                    rows = GetRows(cBox)
                };
            }
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializerNamespaces _ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            _ns.Add("", "");
            serializer.Serialize(writer, root, _ns);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();
        }
        private List<string> GetRows(ComboBox cBox)
        {
            List<string> rows = new List<string>();
            foreach (string row in cBox.Items)
            {
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            return rows;
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("root")]
    public class Root
    {

        [XmlElement("boxes")]
        public List<Box> boxes { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot("Box")]
    public class Box
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("rows")]
        public List<string> rows { get; set; }
    }

}
```